# How to fix cursor type or prevent it from changing

Tags: java, swing, cursor-position

I am working on a Jtable and I fixed the columns widths using:

`colModel.getColumn(0).setMinWidth(15);
    colModel.getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(15);
    colModel.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(15);`

but even so when hovering over the table edges/borders the double sided arrow cursos appears as if prompting the user to expand the columns. I want either to have the cursor type fixed throughout the whole dialog or prevent it from changing into this cursor in this specific instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be fine to use [TableColumn#setResizable(false)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumn.html#setResizable-boolean-) method together.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class ResizeCursorTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(10, 3));

    TableColumnModel colModel = table.getColumnModel();
    colModel.getColumn(0).setMinWidth(15);
    colModel.getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(15);
    colModel.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(15);
    colModel.getColumn(0).setResizable(false);

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new ResizeCursorTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```